# What is the correct way to write a .conf file?

Tags: c#, string, integer

I'm trying to compile a ready-made project, in which a .conf file is missing, I tried to write this file but I always get errors like "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."  What is the correct way to write the .conf file for this code? From what I've seen, you have to declare a value for Host: 127.0.0.1;
Port: 29300;
PwVersion : 156;

```
namespace CoreAutoMessage.Models;

public record GProvider : IPwDaemonConfig
{
    public string Host { get; private init; }
    public int Port { get; private init; }
    public int PwVersion { get; private init; }

    public GProvider()
    {
        var gproviderConfs = File.ReadAllLines("./Configurations/GProvider.conf");

        this.Host = gproviderConfs[1];
        this.Port = int.Parse(gproviderConfs[3]);
        this.PwVersion = int.Parse(gproviderConfs[5]);
    }
}
```

GProvider.conf =

```
Host:127.0.0.1
Port:29300
PwVersion:156
```

Comment: I think your value has space in the beginning. and that is why it is complaining while converting it to `int`.can you share GProvider.conf file as well

Comment: i just added these lines in an empty .conf file. I followed patterns that I've seen ready in other projects, I tried in other ways too, but I always declare it as a string
 Host:127.0.0.1
Port:29300
PwVersion:156

Comment: can you add the file content in the original format in your question? If you really want help from us

Comment: I added, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the format:

```
Host: or literally anything here.
127.0.0.1
Port:
29300
PwVersion:
156
```

The `ReadAllLines` method returns an array of strings, literally lines, separated by endline character. And in your code you are just looking for specified line numbers, 1 3 5, numeration from 0.

Comment: so the numbers, i figured it was something like that, but not that i should skip a line, you really opened my mind. Thank you very much

Comment: @Adrian this is wrong as per your given .conf file. you have only 3 lines

Comment: @viveknuna Please, reread the question. Adrian has the ready code to run but he does not have the actual config file, so he asked for help to create this file. If im not missing anything

Comment: @SergeySosunov OP has added the content in the question

Comment: @viveknuna Yes, but the text of the question literally contains `What is the correct way to write the .conf file for this code?`. So, code should not be touched and only config file needs to be fixed. At which point my logic is invalid?

Comment: @SergeySosunov Its ok. I will let the OP take decision

Comment: yes, I expressed  wrong in my question, but in both ways I understood and learned how it should be created, both the way it was in the ready code, and modifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

so there are only three lines in your file.

```
string host = gproviderConfs[0].Split(':')[1];
int port = int.Parse(gproviderConfs[1].Split(':')[1]);
int version = int.Parse(gproviderConfs[2].Split(':')[1]);
```

you need to get the value after the `:`, there are many ways to do this.

You can also get the value after the first `:` of each line.
In this example I have spliitted the value by `:` and taking the second item

```
int port = int.Parse(gproviderConfs[1].Substring(gproviderConfs[1].IndexOf(':') + 1));
```

Comment: really, now I understand everything! Thank you very much

Comment: @Adrian you should be clear with your question and the posted answers. ideally, the conf file has a key and value on the same line

Comment: yes, I apologize, as I'm learning, I still don't know the correct way to ask for help since I don't understand my mistake